# Map sometimes not loading - initMap is not a function

Tags: google-maps

I use the Google Maps API on my webpage. Sometimes the map is working but *sometimes not. The error i get when the map is not working is* "initMap is not a function"*.

```
<div id="map">
</div>
<script>
        window.initMap = function(){
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.037596, 8.303537), 
                zoom: 13,
            });
        }
</script>
```

I load the maps scripts before the closing body tag. The scripts is loaded from the Wordpress functions.php.

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="" defer="" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXX&amp;libraries=places&amp;callback=initMap"></script>
```

The existing posts to this topic couldn't help me. I also tried without defer and async and with just defer. Withous success. I also put the whole init.Map function inside a jQuery document.ready.

Comment: Have you tried using the API include as in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#step-2-add-the-api-key-to-your-request) (or [with libraries](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries))? (i.e. instead of `<script type="text/javascript" async="" defer="" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXX&amp;libraries=places&amp;callback=initMap"></script>`, no `&amp;`:  `<script type="text/javascript" async defer src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXXXXX&libraries=places&callback=initMap"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted works as expected (with a valid API key and a height set on the map container).

```css
#map {
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map">
</div>
<script>
  window.initMap = function() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.037596, 8.303537),
      zoom: 13,
    });
  }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" async="" defer="" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&amp;libraries=places&amp;callback=initMap"></script>
```